# Comparing version' to display the changes has never worked in CQ5 page

Tags: aem

Manually creating two versions of a page.Click diff to compare current and original versions. The dfferences should be highlighted but only the current version is seen.

A previous version can be restored but it is not possible to see what the previous version looks like before choosing to restore it.
This works fine in Geometrix site. Please help me

Comment: As per the official documentation of AEM. "This feature is available for the text, the image, the text-image and the title components" Just check if you are using the comparison on these component types.